# Redhat OSP13 undercloud upgrade fails

Tags: openstack, rhel, rhel7

Error at the end :

```
2019-12-20 17:07:40,622 INFO:
2019-12-20 17:07:40,623 INFO: [2019-12-20 17:07:40,621] (os-refresh-config) [ERROR] Aborting...
2019-12-20 17:07:40,641 DEBUG: An exception occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instack_undercloud/undercloud.py", line 2441, in install
    _run_orc(instack_env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instack_undercloud/undercloud.py", line 1618, in _run_orc
    _run_live_command(args, instack_env, 'os-refresh-config')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instack_undercloud/undercloud.py", line 675, in _run_live_command
    raise RuntimeError('%s failed. See log for details.' % name)
RuntimeError: os-refresh-config failed. See log for details.
2019-12-20 17:07:40,643 ERROR:
#############################################################################
Undercloud upgrade failed.

Reason: os-refresh-config failed. See log for details.
```

While looking at the logs, I found there was a warning :

```
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'openstacklib' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules.
```

There seems to be a lot of 'Unmet Dependencies' when I run 'puppet module list --tree' is run. I tried installing one of them manually using 'puppet module install' command but the dependency still seems to be present.

Is there anything else to be done to get the undercloud upgrade to work ?

Comment: You can ignore those `unmet dependencies` errors from Puppet. You need to figure why `os-refresh-config` is failing. There are probably details in another log file; I would start by looking for any errors under `/var/log` and see what you find.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @larsks. I do see some errors in /home/stack/.instack/install-undercloud.log.  
`2019-12-23 14:23:54,433 INFO: Error: Command exceeded timeout
2019-12-23 14:23:54,434 INFO: Error: /Stage[main]/Mistral::Db::Sync/Exec[mistral-db-populate]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Command exceeded timeout 2019-12-23 14:28:54,443 INFO: Error: /Stage[main]/Mistral::Db::Sync/Exec[mistral-db-populate]: Failed to call refresh: Command exceeded timeout
2019-12-23 14:28:54,443 INFO:Error: /Stage[main]/Mistral::Db::Sync/Exec[mistral-db-populate]: Command exceeded timeout`